# What is the best way to get duration of a GIF in Java Android?

Tags: android, gif, duration

I'm finding the way to get duration of a GiF. Is there any function like getDuration() for Gif?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could open the GIF as a [Movie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html) and check the duration:

```
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_gif);
    Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    int duration = movie.duration();
```

Duration is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. But it seems to work slowly for display information on screen. Anyway, it is a good idea for getting duration of a GIF.

Comment: I am getting the gif URL and displaying it into the imageview. now, how can I get the length. please help

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @samgak was working perfectly, and it works if input video is from assets (raw) folder.

But if we have input video path from device storage then just pass videoPath to `Movie` class like below:

```
Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(videoPath);
int duration = movie.duration();
```

and it works fine (for me it's working very well, just a little problem is that it takes a little longer to calculate duration).

Comment: I am getting the gif URL and displaying it into the imageview. now, how can I get the length. please help

Comment: can you please try `String.valueOf(uri)` instead of direct `uri`(i don't know if this will work or not for your case but you should try).